# javascript alternative to ruby .none?

Tags: javascript, boolean, iteration, conditional-statements

How can I iterate and `do something` if none meet conditions. For context in Ruby I can do `some_array.none?{|t| t == "something"}` and get a boolean back.

In js I'm trying to iteratate all elements with an [href] prop and do something if none have the class "active"

```
$("[href]").each(function() {
    if (this.href == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

I do the above to style my active links but I want one of my links to be set active if none of the others are. I'm new to js so im sure there might be a better approach to this.

Comment: Use [.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and invert the condition. E.g. if you want to check if none are odd, then `[1, 2, 3].every(x => x%2 == 0)`

Comment: not sure how to implement this from the snippet you posted I tried this but didnt work 


    ```if ($("[href]").every(!this.hasClass("active"))) {
        $("[href='/snippets/new']").addClass("active");
    }```


maybe give an example closer to my specific use case ?

Comment: @Daniel-StudentDev Use `Array.from($("[href]")).every`. jQuery collections don't have these methods

Comment: Btw, also `!….some(…)`

Comment: @Bergi I dont understand your comment and @vlaz i tried this ```if (Array.from($("[href]")).every(!this.hasClass("active"))) {
        $("[href='/snippets/new']").addClass("active");
    }``` and did not work .. guys please understand I am new to JS  a full snippet might be more helpful :(

Comment: You need to pass a callback function to `every`, similar to how you have to pass a function to `each`. `Array.from(…).every(el => !$(el).hasClass("active"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you move the selector condition into the jQuery selector, then test the selector length?

```
var selector = $("[href=" + window.location.href + "]");
selector.each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

if(selector.length == 0) {
    $("[href='/snippets/new/]").addClass("active");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I accomplished what I wanted but its a bit hacky and ugly so still open to alternatives here's what I did

```
var counter = 0;
$("[href]").each(function() {
    if (this.href == window.location.href) {
        counter = +1;
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});

if (counter === 0) {
    $("[href='/snippets/new']").addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: You probably should either increment the *counter* using `counter += 1`, or use a boolean flag that you set to `true`.

Comment: Yea i refactored just wanted to see if worked I ended up going with keywords 

```var status = "none";

    $("[href]").each(function() {
        if (this.href == window.location.href) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
         status = "found";
        }
    });
    if (status === "none") { $("[href$='dashboard']").addClass("active"); }```

Comment: ill go with boolean that would look a look a little prettier thanks